# Display only specific attachments

Tags: 2010

I'm trying to list the attachments of a list item depending on it's name. But I have no idea how to get the name attribute into the if condition:

```
<xsl:if test="????????">
      <xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
          <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>                        
          <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
             <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
```

Who can help me?